# How to get date difference(number of days) in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have two date objects which I need to subtract them to get number of days as its difference in python 3.x.

They are dtype: objects type. How can I get the difference?

Comment: Can you give an example of how these dates look like?

Comment: X['construction_year'].head(3)
01-01-1999
01-01-201001-01-2009
Name: construction_year, dtype: object

X['date_recorded'].head(3)
Out[14]: 
0    14-03-2011
1    06-03-2013
2    25-02-2013
Name: date_recorded, dtype: object

Comment: X['construction_year'].head(3)
01-01-1999
01-01-2010  
Name: construction_year, dtype: object

X['date_recorded'].head(3)
14-03-2011
06-03-2013
25-02-2013
Name: date_recorded, dtype: object

Comment: Please add the details to your question using [edit] instead of posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example to get difference between two dates:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.date(2017, 6, 30)
b = datetime.date(2017, 3, 21)
c = a-b
```

and c =  datetime.timedelta(101)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-33a0112f4628>", line 2, in <module>
    a = datetime.date(X['date_recorded'][i])

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: First you have to save your dtype as datetime, afterwards you can get the timedelta. example: a = datetime.strptime('01-01-1999', '%d-%M-%Y'), and then do the timedelta.

Comment: Yes, I got the difference but in timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object format need to extract days.

Comment: Edit please the initial question and add what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Hamperfait for your response, I got the desired result.